# Can't read line from html page

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to cut the time format from a specific site. The regex is working (tried with regex tester and worked), but when I try to run the code in Python I get:

```
import urllib,re

sock = urllib.urlopen("http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=time")
htmlSource = sock.read()
sock.close()
ips = re.findall( r'([01]?[0-9]{1}|2[0-3]{1}):[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}',htmlSource)
print ips
```

The result:

```
>>>
['7', '4']
>>>
```

The time on [regextester.com](http://www.regextester.com/) is marked with red color I want to extract the time in the following format: xx:xx:xx (24h).

Why is it happening? Thank you!

Comment: You used a regex tester to test that regex against Wolfram Alpha's giant AJAX app source and it worked?

Comment: What is your expected output? What is the text that you're parsing? Print out `htmlSource` and ensure it's what you think it is, and tell us what your *expected* results should be. It looks to me like you're trying to extract the hour from a time format, and it looks like it's doing that successfully, so what's the issue?

Comment: With the following site:http://www.regextester.com/
The time is marked with red color

I want to extract the time in the following format: xx:xx:xx (24h)

Answer (score 1):

You have some redundant quantifiers in your regexp (those `{1}`). You can remove them.

Another thing is that `re.findall` is returning only your captures, which are the hours. Change the first capture to a non-caturing group `(?: ... )` and capture the whole regex:

```
((?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])
```

This should be doing it I think.

Comment: This is working, thank you very much ! sorry for the stupid mistake. I hope to learn regex better now.

Comment: @user180894 That's okay, I don't think it was a stupid mistake, but a valid question! I hope the downvotes don't discourage you too much. I'm not sure why your question was downvoted...